# How to avoid repeating blocks of XAML in a menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have to create a menu. It has 10 entries and they differ by one parameter.

Entry 1:

```
<MenuItem Visibility="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='PAZ', Mode=OneWay}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CmdContextMenu}" CommandParameter="PAZ" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <MenuItem.Header>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                        Foreground="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='PAZ', Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Text="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToIconConverter}, ConverterParameter='PAZ', Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="{StaticResource XSmallLeftMargin}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="PAZ" />
      </Grid>
   </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Entry 2:

```
<MenuItem Visibility="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='APP', Mode=OneWay}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CmdContextMenu}" CommandParameter="APP" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <MenuItem.Header>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                        Foreground="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='APP', Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Text="{Binding MenuSelected.Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToIconConverter}, ConverterParameter='APP', Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="{StaticResource XSmallLeftMargin}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="APP" />
      </Grid>
   </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

As you can see, the only difference is between `PAZ` and `APP` in different points... and same goes on for all the others.
Is there a way I can avoid to repeat it 10 times just changing the 3 letters?

I do not want to use code-behind to create the menu dynamically... but to process it from XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I assume that `CmdContextMenu` and `MenuSelected` are properties on your main view model and not in a separate menu item type. If this is different, you have to adapt the code accordingly.

In order to remove the redundant code, create a collection for your menu items in your view model.

```
public class MyMainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public IEnumerable<string> MyTypes { get; } = new List<string>
   {
      "PAZ",
      "APP"
   };

   // ...other properties and methods (like "CmdContextMenu" and "MenuSelected" I Assume).
}
```

Next, you have to change the value converters, because the [`ConverterParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter?view=net-5.0) is not a dependency property and cannot be bound. Instead, you can use [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=net-5.0)s that can bind multiple values. Adapt all of your converters to implement `IMultiValueConverter`. Here is an example of how a converter could look like. Of course, it depends on your implementation. In essence, use the `values` array to access bound values.

```
public class TypeToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return values[0].Equals(values[1]) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Next, create a data template for the header of your menu items. As you can see, the bindings are replaced with `MultiBinding`s that use an `IMultiValueConverter` as `Converter`.

The first binding in each block is a `RelativeSource` binding to access the data context of the parent `Menu`, because I assume that the `MenuSelected` property is defined on your main view model. The other empty bindings will bind to the data context of the current menu item, which is an item from the `MyTypes` collection.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyMenuItemHeaderTemplate" DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
         <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}">
               <Binding Path="DataContext.MenuSelected.Type" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
               <Binding/>
            </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Foreground>
         <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TypeToIconConverter}">
               <Binding Path="DataContext.MenuSelected.Type" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
               <Binding/>
            </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="{StaticResource XSmallLeftMargin}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Create a new header item style that uses this data template. The `Visibility` also uses a multi-value converter as above. Instead of using an event trigger, you can simply assign the command to the menu item directly and pass a `CommandParameter`, which is bound to the data context of the current menu item.

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
   <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyMenuItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
   <Setter Property="Visibility">
      <Setter.Value>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TypeToVisibilityConverter}">
            <Binding Path="DataContext.MenuSelected.Type" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CmdContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
</Style>
```

Finally, create a `Menu` and bind the `MyTypes` collection, as well as the style.

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypes}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyMenuItemStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry but I get this error: XDG0008 String is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project
            

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyMenuItemHeaderTemplate" DataType="{x:Type system:String}">

even if I tried to add: xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

I'm using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @MassimoSavazzi That namespace is only available in .NET Framework, for .NET Core, use `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"` instead.

Comment: Now a small additional challenge to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147745/how-to-create-a-contextmenu-with-items-generated-from-binding-and-directly

Answer (score 0):

1. ConverParameter property is not a DependencyProperty - so it cannot be Bound to.
   You can use a MultiValue converter instead.
2. Instead of creating 10 menu items in xaml manually, you should be able to bind an ItemsCollection and define a `DataTemplate` for MenuItem